# How to disable play button of YouTube embed code in rich editor?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed

What I want to do is to remove YouTube embed code by 2 clicks. 
First, when you click the YouTube display, show the remove icon at just above it. Second, when you click the remove icon, YouTube display is removed.

[This is code I'm working on.](https://jsfiddle.net/hiro14/19615ojn/2/)
My problem is when I click YouTube display, YouTube start.
To avoid this I added div.media-frame and gave `z-index:1` to it. But it doesn't work.
How can I show remove icon without starting YouTube and remove it?

Comment: So put a layer on top of it...

Comment: I thought div.media-frame is layer but it doesn't work. What's wrong with this?